# mailchimp deleted member list produces error 400 if added again with API v3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp

I am using gibbon / rails app to manage my member list on mailchimp using API v3.

It happens that after I deleted a member it actually is'nt there anymore as I can see in my dashboard but ant subsequent attempt to reinsert the member in the list produces error 400 @title="Member Exists" as result.

That's pretty weird, any ideaa?

Answer (score 0):

Tried again after 4 hours then I could re-inscribe the members I deleted.

It seems there is a "protection" timeframe of a few hours between deletion - reinsertion which is not documented at all.